# TDS project not loading while migrating solution from VS 2013 to VS 2017

Tags: tds, visual-studio

I am in the process of migrating my solution from VS 2013 to VS 2017. I installed the correct version of TDS (TDS `5.6.0.15` for VS 2017) and when trying to open the solution in VS 2017, TDS projects are not loading and throwing following error.

[image: TDS - Project Target Framework Not Installed]

Tried an option in the error dialog box to convert TDS project to `.NET Framework 4.6.1` but it does nothing and TDS projects are still not loading. Not sure how to fix it.

Do I really need `.NET Framework 4.0` installed on this machine?

Would appreciate if someone can chime in with a solution for similar migration.

Below is `PropertyGroup` node from Project definition file (`.csproj`).

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{1a9cd7e6-633b-4cfd-a018-c68ce1f57482}</ProjectGuid>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <SourceWebPhysicalPath>..\GexaNes.Web</SourceWebPhysicalPath>
    <SourceWebProject>{b8d502fa-286e-45e9-b41f-584dadd80d16}|GexaNes.Web\GexaNes.Web.csproj</SourceWebProject>
    <SourceWebVirtualPath>/GexaNes.Web.csproj</SourceWebVirtualPath>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <EnableUpdateable>true</EnableUpdateable>
    <UseMerge>true</UseMerge>
    <SingleAssemblyName>GexaNes.TDS.Core</SingleAssemblyName>
    <UseWebConfigReplacement>false</UseWebConfigReplacement>
    <DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>true</DeleteAppCodeCompiledFiles>
    <LegacyFileReplacement>false</LegacyFileReplacement>
    <AssemblyName>GexaNes.TDS.Core</AssemblyName>
    <Name>GexaNes.TDS.Core</Name>
    <RootNamespace>GexaNes.TDS.Core</RootNamespace>
    <SitecoreDatabase>core</SitecoreDatabase>
    <SccProjectName>
    </SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>
    </SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>
    </SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>
    </SccLocalPath>
    <EnableCodeGeneration>false</EnableCodeGeneration>
    <ManageRoles>False</ManageRoles>
    <AssemblyStatus>Exclude</AssemblyStatus>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ....
</Project>
```

Comment: Did you tried to update the `.Net Framework` to `4.6.1` of the different projects manually? Moreover can you try to update the `targetFramework` manually by editing the `.scproj` via notepad?

Comment: All my projects in solution are already configured for 4.6.1 in VS 2013. Yes, I also tried to edit .scproj manually but that is not working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this by re-installing VS 2010.
I had VS 2010 which I uninstalled as I am not using it anymore but after reinstalling it back, I am able to load TDS project correctly in VS 2017.

Someone mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570827/net-framework-4-0-does-not-install-when-4-5-is-already-installed) a repair option, which I didn't try but looks like it can resolve such issues. May be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I remember running into this issue a while back.

To address it I had to download manually the .net Framework on the corresponding version(in my case I think it was 4.5) and install it on my environment. After that the TDS project would load properly.

Hopefully this is an option on your side

Comment: I tried that option but it didn't work.